# My bcrypt gem isnt working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bcrypt-ruby

I have successfully installed `bcrypt - 3.1.7`, and bundle installed after that.

However, the bcrypt gem doesnt show up in the list, when I try to bundle show bcrypt, it says:

```
Could not find gem 'bcrypt'.
```

Also, when I do:

`gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'`

it says:

`ERROR:  While executing gem.. (Gem::CommandLineError) Unknown command bcrypt`

What should I do?

Comment: try restarting server console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of:

```
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
```

try:

```
gem install bcrypt -v 3.1.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
```